# Oracle sql developer does not create services

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I extracted oracle sql developer, ran the program; it opens. When i try to create a database and connect to it , it gives me a

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=TepXC7PiSV+8cVIT/ElMdw==)

Vendor code 17002

error; i looked at services, there is no oracle service at all in my services.

lsnrctl command isn't recognized in cmd.

; there is no ORACLE_HOME or etc either in my path vars.

It's like oracle isn't installed. But it tells me in the docs all i need to do to install SQL developer is to extract the folder and run the exe. Thats what i did.

There is no preinstallation mentioned in the docs? Am i doing something stupid?

i had installed no oracle product prior to this other than Oracle VMBox and java and jdk. So if something is assumed to already be installed, i didn't install anything else Oracle related.

I use a TPlink wireless adapter, if its any reason for this at all.

Comment: SQL Developer is a *client*, not a database server. See [I have Oracle SQL Developer Installed, Now What?](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/). There are now Docker and other options available as well as the pre-built VMs mentioned in that article, if you don't want to get involved with the full installation process. If you have VirtualBox already then consider using one of those pre-builts.